What does "so I'm not" mean?
In Poor Things (2023), Duncan Wedderburn, a debauched lawyer, became upset when he
discovered Bella, a childlike young woman, having physical
intimacy with another man:

Duncan: Did you furious jump him?
Bella: No...he just fast-licked my clitoris. I had the heat
that needed release, so at my request, it was. You, too, may
tongue play me, so I'm not understanding this complicated feeling.
Are you now crying?

It’s a complex sentence with two independent clauses connected by the
conjunction “so”.
What does "so I'm not" mean ?

Duncan appears jealous because Bella is letting another man lick her genitals. She  points out that he, too is allowed to do that so. (therefore) she is not understanding his jealousy. She is possibly being disingenuous or stupid, or, more likely, letting him know that she considers their relationship to be purely physical, and that he has no right to feel any jealousy about her intimacy with others.

I was going to criticise this, but I found out the film is based on a 1992 book, Poor Things: Episodes from the Early Life of Archibald McCandless M.D., Scottish Public Health Officer by Alasdair Gray, who I like very much.

"so I'm not" isn't a unit. "So" is connecting the first part with "I'm not understanding". Also note that Bella doesn't use regular idiomatic or grammatical English which is one of the chief points of the book and film, something I fear you may have missed with not being a native speaker.

I’m voting to close this question because there's no point in trying to learn English from the speech patterns of Bella in Poor Things. Her utterances are carefully crafted by the scriptwriters to be understandable to native Anglophones whilst at the same time being uniquely unnatural.

@MichaelHarvey Why is everybody being taken by these questions?

@FumbleFingers Have you looked at the other questions? This OP is mother tongue English (he said that in a comment to me). And his questions bear this out. They are not a question a mother tongue person would ask and the English is fine in every single one. What does that tell you?

@Lambie - I've been as lavish with the downvotes to this person as I dare.

@Lambie: On the basis of this Q, I suppose this OP gets a kick out of publicly analyzing salacious texts. But if that's a problem, it's really for the mods to deal with

@Lambie - what does it tell you? I'm feeling a bit slow on the uptake today.

@FumbleFingers - and the OP probably has a mental and/or chronological age of around 13.

@MichaelHarvey: We being older and wiser, then, we shouldn't be phased by one "rogue" OP. For this specific question, it's reasonable to vtc purely on the grounds that the text being queried is deliberately "non-standard". If it was a different OP, someone might want to point out that I'm not understanding this could be "Indian English" for I don't understanding this. But Bella's weird speech patterns don't really have any connection to IE, and the OP looks like a time-waster anyway, so there's probably no point in looking into that aspect.

@FumbleFingers You guys are not understanding me. ha ha. And that ain't "Indian English". I think he's taking the [blank] and everyone's going down the rabbit hole. [Btw, at some point a while back someone told me that that British expression is "dirty". Geesus, what are we coming to?]

@FumbleFingers - I'm rarely fazed these days by anything I see on here.

The key part of the sentence is "I'm not understanding", which means the same as "I do not understand".
Bella is saying the because Duncan can also do the same as was done to Bella ("so..."), she does not understand the "complicated feeling".
"I'm not understanding" is an unusual way of saying "I do not understand", but Bella doesn't talk normally and this is one example.

I don't think it's that unusual in a conversation. I'm not understanding you/you're not understanding me!
